# I am not able to share URL image using share plugin for EDGE browser

Tags: javascript, mongodb, keystonejs

[image]

I have added "Share on Facebook" button to my project. When I click on it, it will open the Facebook share model window and when I click share button present on Facebook model window nothing happens, it is not responding.

Can you help?

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to share facebook URL, image, title and description on edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865201/not-able-to-share-facebook-url-image-title-and-description-on-edge-browser)

Comment: My code is working on firefox and chrome browser but I think Edge is not supported to share facebook.
Is there any other solution for this issue.